# How to disable "Available" on the Application display?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-netbook, software-center

When I use the Search Application box, I keep getting suggestions for applications, which boggle the speed of the search down to a halt (The whole thing is very slow as it is, on a EEEpc netbook), Is there a way to make Unity stop offering suggestions? I can't find anywhere to actually configure that thing

Answer (score 2):

This problems needs to be reported as a feature request/bug to the unity bug tracker:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity

Because the solution will be to have a code solution or improve the speed of apt-cache.